# Multiple Json Entries to one struct

Tags: json, go

I have multiple JSON files, I want to put into one call in an API.

Following is my struct:

```golang
type Demo struct {
    ChannelID int      `json:"channelId"`
    SeriesName string  `json:"seriesName"`
}
```

And I have 5 JSON files, I need to put into this struct, and pass on into an API call.

How do I do that?

Here's my code:

```golang
func GetJson(search string) *models.Demo {
    jsonStruct := models.Demo{}
    assetIds := DecodeXml(search)
    for i := 0; i < len(assetIds); i++ {
        epgData, err := http.Get(assets.EpgUrl + fmt.Sprintf("%v", assetIds[i]))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(epgData.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }           
        json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &jsonStruct)
    }
    return &jsonStruct
}
```

For my API call, I use gin-gonic, with following code:

```golang
type Search struct {
    Search string `form:"search"`
}


func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/search", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var search Search
        if c.ShouldBind(&search) == nil {
            c.JSON(200, actions.GetJson(search.Search))
        }
    })

    r.Run()
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You have only an object of `Demo` struct. What you need is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a single variable `jsonStruct` and repeatedly overwrite its value. You should create a slice of `Demo` values and fill the slice.

This code example uses and returns a slice of `Demo` values.

```golang
func GetJson(search string) []models.Demo {
    assetIds := DecodeXml(search)
    jsonStructs := make([]models.Demo, len(assetIds))
    for i := 0; i < len(assetIds); i++ {
        epgData, err := http.Get(assets.EpgUrl + fmt.Sprintf("%v", assetIds[i]))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(epgData.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }           
        epgData.Body.Close()
        json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &jsonStructs[i])
    }
    return jsonStructs
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks!

Though, the next problem occurs.
When i make a few calls to my api, it just adds the new result to the bottom of my result.
Example, if i search for a keyword, and then another keyword in a other call. Those two keywords get's combined and showed by the api

Comment: @Exobit One thing missing in my code and yours is the closing of the Body. I added this. I’m not sure if it’s related to your next problem. The problem you report may be on the side of the API, not your code. Do you see this behavior when performing the requests by hand with curl ?

Comment: When i request by curl, a new set of results gets returned.

I Tried to add the body.clode(), but unfortunately it doesn't work

I use gin-gonic for my api. I added my code for the api call

Comment: @Exobit the `Close` was needed anyway. It’s not clear, based of the code you gave, what could cause this next problem. The problem could be in the code of `DecodeXml`. Could you add this code in your question ?

Comment: I actually found out, that in my ```DecodeXML``` i declared a global variable with my struct, not in the function. That explains why i just kept adding my with Id's.

But thank you so much!

Comment: @Exobit good job. Couldn't help you in that without the code of DecodeXML